# How is a threat to public order and/or national security determined for visa-free entry to a Schengen country?

Tags: schengen-visas, security

If someone with a terrorism conviction from Canada, dating back more than 13 years, is attempting to travel for leisure to a Schengen-area country, what are the chances that they will be refused entry? The client does not yet have a Canadian pardon, but has completed their prison sentence. They only have a Canadian passport. They are rehabilitated and are a productive member of society in Canada.

The Schengen-area agreements state that someone will be refused if they are deemed a threat to public order, national security, or will negatively affect international relations. On what grounds is this determined? Does anyone know of case law where this clause has been interpreted and applied? Is a previous serious criminal conviction in itself sufficient to demonstrate a threat to public order? Is a decade-old terrorism conviction itself sufficient to demonstrate a current threat to national security? Assume that the country they are trying to go to is the Netherlands.

Comment: [Europol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europol) (or other international police organisations) entries would be a major factor that could lead to a refused entry. If Canada has not (or no longer) listed you as an active threat, then the checks done during the entry into the Schengen Area will probably return negative.

Comment: Different national services may have a list (black list, and probably a larger list of potential people to ban). I do not think you may find any published rule. but possibly some of them "inciting violence or disobedience or threatening existence of states or territories" (on previous months), "supposed member of a terrorist organization, or link to them), "bad crimes to the traveling country, which may cause severe clash on public". As I said: it is not well publicity documented, and there is no need of case-law. Other states may complain.

Comment: The question title asks about a visa application but the body asks about refusal at the border.  Which is it?  I suppose the answer is the same legally speaking, but the administrative details will differ considerably, probably including the evidence available to the decision maker and the time available to make the decision.

Comment: @phoog As a Canadian passport holder (as written inside the question) it is clear that the OP does not require a visa. For those who would require a visa, a similar check would be done, as when entering, during the application process.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I missed "they only have a Canadian passport."  The title of the question is misleading and ought to be changed.  During a visa application there is time for a more thorough investigation of an applicant's criminal records than at a passport inspection checkpoint (though I do not know to what extent consulates of any Schengen country would perform a more thorough investigation, if at all).

Answer (score 6):

It is unfortunately impossible to tell unless the person actually shows up at a Schengen border and seeks entry.

Unlike many other countries, the Schengen area does not have a system where certain types of criminal convictions lead to an automatic inadmissibility. Each case will be decided on an individual basis. It is hard to imagine that a conviction for terrorism (without knowing the details) will *not* weigh heavily against the person when evaluating if the person is a 'threat to public order'. On the other side, it is an advantage that the conviction is so old.

Some other countries, like e.g. UK and US allow the traveller to apply for a visa in advance if in doubt, even if the traveller comes from a visa exempt country. This is unfortunately not the case for the Schengen area. A Canadian citizen can not apply for a short term visa to ascertain if he is admissable.

Having said that, I would however assume that the chances that anyone finds out about the conviction during immigration control are close to zero. AFAIK, Canadian authorities does not share data with any of the Schengen countries and unless anything else triggers a more thorough check, chances are high that any Canadian citizen seeking entry to the Schengen area will be 'waved through' without any fuzz.

Comment: OP could wait until ETIAS becomes active to (most likely) know in advance. Of course determining when ETIAS will become available requires a crystal ball.

Comment: Note that even without information sharing, a terrorism conviction is most likely public information, and security services would really not be being their job if they didn’t know about it. The question is rather whether later evaluations have determined that the person is no longer deemed a risk.

Comment: @jcaron but the degree to which security services seek out public information of that sort proactively, so it would be available in a database used by an immigration officer, is probably somewhat limited.

Comment: @jcaron I think you are vastly overestimating the resources and level of cooperation between intelligence and border protection services. At least in this case, the information may be available online and in English but Canada is also unlikely to be a major focus of data collection…